# How to fit a joint model using the JM package in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, longitudinal

Im doing a joint model analysis by using the JM-package from R. Therefore I need to fit a linear mixed model and a Cox survival model first:

```
lmefit <- lme(DEST ~ Week + FL + FT + 
                      DAC + Age + Gender + MED, random = ~ 1|ID, 
                    data = Long_Set, na.action = na.omit)

coxFit <- coxph(Surv(TT_Event, Event) ~ FT + MED + DAC,
                    data = Event_Set, x = TRUE)
```

My joint model looks as follows:

```
jointFit <- jointModel(lmefit, coxFit, timeVar = "Week")
```

Now when im running the joint model I get the following error: 
"Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  Can't fit a Cox model with 0 failures"

I dont understand this because my dataframes have both ones and zeros in the Event column and also the mixed/cox model output indicate that events have 111 events have been detected. For the lme (number of obs = 1205 and groups = 194) and for the cox (number of obs = 194 and events = 111).

My dataframe for the longitudinal/lme part look something like this (not all variables are present here):

```
dfL <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), DEST = c(0.4, 1.8, 1.2, 3.2, 3.6, 2.8), Week = c(0, 4, 16, 4, 20, 8), Event = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), TT_Event = c(16, 20, 8))
```

And for the survival/cox part looks very similar:

```
dfC <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), DEST = c(1.2, 3.6, 2.8, 2.4, 1.9, 3.4), Week = c(16, 20, 8, 36, 24, 32), Event = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), TT_Event = c(16, 20, 8, 36, 24, 32))
```

Furthermore I dont have any missing values or something so I dont know whats going wrong here

Thnx :)

Comment: I have no experience with the "JM" package (didn't even know of its existence) but is it possible that some sort of stratification is occurring in which one of the strata has the particular feature being described in the error message? The other theory (similarly on a flimsy basis) is that the data arguments need to refer to the same data.

Comment: Good suggestion.. ill try to look into that later... however it seems to work now after subtracting the final week of each subject by 1 in the longitudinal dataset (dfL).. not optimal but do-able i guess.. maybe the model needs a unique time to event which cannot correspond with the longitudinal time markers??

Comment: Have you tried putting `verbose=T` within the `jointModel` function? It might identify where the model is breaking down. You could also try different `method` arguments.